# Filling in areas between lines with polygons in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, line, trace, fill

I have to make a geographical map.

[image: the map]

I have to fill in the gaps between the lines with polygons. Is there a possibility to just trace those lines automatically?

I have to do everything manually now, which takes a lot of time.
Right now I am using the `"Add object polygon"` from the digitalizing toolbar.

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263946/line-tracing-on-scanned-map-in-qgis answer your question?

Comment: Can you use the lines to polygons or polygonize tools to create polygons?  You might have to put in a temporary line around your area of interest so they all build.  Another option is to great a polygon for your area of interest and then use the split with lines tool to cut that into polygons?

Answer (score 0):

Additional information like what version are you using? From the looks of the screen shot I'm guessing it's not Arc Pro.

You absolutely can trace lines to create a polygon.

Create an empty polygon for editing. (Either in gdb or shapefile)

Open an edit session. Go to the Editor tool bar - Editor drop down and select More Editing Tools.

Select the Advanced editing. There is a Trace tool on that tool bar you can use to create the polygon shapefile.

NOTE: sometimes while tracing (if it seems to 'hang up') you need to move your mouse back / forth over the line. I think this happens when there are tons of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. create a new layer and draw a big square around the entire map in it
2. use the "Vector"/"Geoprocessing Tools"/"Difference..." tool between the new layer and the layer with gaps
3. apply "Vector"/"Geometry Tools"/"Multipart to singleparts..." on the result of the difference.
4. Now you have a layer with all gap-polygons digitized and you either append it to the original layer or you can copy the polygons from that layer to the destination layer.